# Angular 7 ControlValueAcessor doesn't propagate the valid status for the parent form

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a component that implements the `Material date-picker` ant uses `moment` to format the date. The value is propagating to the parent form, but the field valid status keep on my component, even if my validation is working.

In the Html of the component i have this: `<mat-error *ngIf="control.invalid">{{ errorMessage}}</mat-error>`, who works: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9TLk6.png)

but this save button, who is the "submit" button of the parent form, have a validation who disable this button if the `formGroup` is invalid, but, even if my component is invalid, the button keeps enabled.

Anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: can you create a stackblitz reproducing the issue

Comment: Sure, give me some minutes

Comment: Hi Leonardo, were you able to fix the issue